# can´t read this closure in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, dictionary, closures

I´ve this closure (that i got here with much THX to dfri!) and don´t know how to transform it:

```
let attributesOverRanges = fooAttrString.getAttributes()
for (rng, attributes) in attributesOverRanges {
    print("Attributes over range \(rng):")
    attributes.forEach { print("\t\($0.0) = \($0.1)") }
}
```

this is some result-line:

```
Attributes over range (0,12):
    NSFont == <UICTFont: 0x7fc7f2d31330> font-family: "Helvetica Neue";    
font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 17.00pt
```

Now i must get the Informations

1. NSRange
2. NSFont
3. font-family: "Helvetica Neue"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 17.00pt

and put it them an array/dictionary. I tried a lot but i can't resolve this, feeling like the absolute Newby i seem to be ( with a terrible english)! :-(

Can u help me, please

After the answer of @rickster, i tried it with for a Bold Font. But i get an error, cause let value = $0.0 don´t retrieve a string but a Font. Can i cast the Font to a string??? I have to find the "bold" in the string. Or do u knnow another way to check Bold

```
let attributesOverRanges = fooAttrString.getAttributes()
var newAttributes: [(NSRange, String)] = []
for (rng, attributes) in attributesOverRanges {
    attributes.forEach {
        let value = $0.0
        if value.contains("font-weight: bold") {    // ERROR
            newAttributes.append((rng, "Bold"))
        }
    }
    print(newAttributes)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forEach` is a method on all sequence types that iterates though the sequence — it's a functional-programming version of the `for`-`in` loop. The closure passed to `forEach` takes one parameter, the current element of the sequence being examined. (For example, in `[1,2,3].forEach { /*...*/ }`, the closure parameter is an integer. In the shortest possible shorthand for writing a closure, you can refer to the parameter as `$0`, so in this example you could write `{ print($0) }` for the closure.)

In your code, `attributes` is a dictionary. When you iterate over a dictionary, the element type is a `(key, value)` tuple. The shortest / label-agnostic way to address the items in a tuple is by index: `foo.0`, `foo.1`, etc.

Putting them together: in your `forEach` closure, `$0.0` is a key in your `attributes` dictionary, and `$0.1` is the corresponding value.

Since you're working with the attributes dictionary of an `NSAttributedString`, keys are attribute names (`"NSFont"` is the value of the `NSFontAttributeName` constant), and values are whatever object type corresponds to that key (in this case, an `NSFont` instance — what you see printed is the summary of a font that you get by asking for its `description`).

You can use them as a key-value pair in another dictionary (`otherDict[$0.0] = $0.1`), or maybe just use the value in an array since there's probably not much need to keep the "NSFont" string around (`myArray.append($0.1)`).

---

Finding out whether an `NSFont` instance represents a bold font is actually not a simple question with a simple answer. Remember that many fonts have a [wide variety of weights](http://martiancraft.com/img/blog/articles/large/20151022_sf_18-weights@2x.png) — usually, a font designer will give weights above some threshold a tag that semantically identifies them as "bold", but not always.

`NSFont` has a companion API `NSFontDescriptor` that lets you get some of this semantic information. Here's a shot at getting that, along with the rest of your info, but you'll need to adapt this to fit your situation:

```
for (rng, attributes) in attributesOverRanges {
    print("NSRange: \(rng) - has attributes:")
    for (name, value) in attributes {
        if name == NSFontAttributeName {
            if let font = value as? NSFont {
                print("font name (use with `NSFont(name:size:)`): \(font.fontName)")

                let isBold = font.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits & UInt32(NSFontBoldTrait) != 0
                print("is bold font: \(isBold)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: THX for your extended declaration  @rickster  How can i check if it´s a Bold font with your way?